# Форматирование текста Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

У меня в боте можно делать рассылки. Когда отправляется текст с форматом Markdown к примеру

> **Тест** @name_test_bot

Сообщение приходит с полностью отформатированным текстом

> **Тест** @name*test*bot

и следовательно по нику нельзя перейти к боту. Так же были попытки ввода HTML и с отправкой вместе с параметром "parse_mode="HTML", но в этом случае сообщение просто не доходило до получателей. Каким образом это можно исправить, и чтобы ники были исправны и можно было нормально форматировать текст?

Comment: приведите ваш код `parse_mode="Markdown"` и `parse_mode="HTML"`

Answer (score 1):

Из документации Telegeram Bot API: To escape characters '_', '*', '`', '[' outside of an entity, prepend the characters '' before them.
То есть вам нужно добавить \ перед нижними подчёркиваниями.